# How to block a package for iOS and not Android inside pubspec.yaml?

Tags: flutter, yaml

I have a specific package for my Flutter app that help me do an Android Specific task, but this package throws an error when compiling for iOS. In Dart I can just block certain task to platform specific using the Platform.isIOS or Platform.isAndroid.

How can I block this package when compiling for iOS, as this is in the pubspec.yaml file. I am a flutter beginner so I don't know much about how it works under the hood.

Comment: Is this about a package that you created or a package from pub.dartlang.org (`depdencies:` in `pubspec.yaml`)?

Comment: It sis a package from pub.dartlang.org. It is this package https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/system_shortcuts

Comment: I don't think you can. Perhaps clone the package, delete the ios directory and add it as path dependency

Comment: is deleting ios directory enough? For me, it gives error "No podspec found for..."@GünterZöchbauer